# Getting the individual dimension behaviour from a multivariate normal model

Tags: confidence-interval, outliers, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am training a multivariate normal model on a set of data (assuming it is the legit case), and then I use this trained model to identify whether a new data point is also legit or a possible outlier depending on the confidence intervals.

My question is the following: is there any way to determine the dimension/s responsible for making a data point an outlier? I mean in case I have 4 features for example as my dimensions and my model predicts that a new data point `x` is an outlier, can I determine which feature of those 4 caused this since some features might have good values but one of them perhaps made `x` a bad point?

#### Edit :

My data is a set of *Amazon reviews* and each review has a bunch of features: `{length, has_image, number_of_helpful_votes, rating}`

I am training my multivariate normal model on a set of legit reviews (I know they are not spam).

For testing I am calculating the `pdf` for each new Amazon review under the trained multivariate model and check whether the value falls within the confidence interval or not (if not then it is considered as an outlier).

In case a review was considered an outlier, is there any way to know which feature is the reason for this from the set `{length, has_image, number_of_helpful_votes, rating}`?, i.e. which dimension caused this point to be out the confidence interval, as I want also to provide a reason for marking this point as an outlier.

of course this can be done manually, but I am asking from a statistical point of view in order to automate the whole process.

Comment: One problem with the approach you describe is that it might not be one specific variable value that creates a multivariate outlier. For instance, two highly correlated variables might have values individually typical, but far out in the marginal distribution. So reconsider your approach!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yes of course this is kept in my mind and the model I explained is just an example. But in case there was no correlation between the features and their behavior is completely independent, is there an answer to my question to know statistically what feature has the major effect on the testing point?